# What exactly is the distance one can teleport?

Tags: marvel-super-heroes

Looking at the teleport powers from the books and also the net supplement ultimate powers I'm unsure. Ultimate powers states Coulmn E on distance table while the core rules say the rank defines the distance. But I find no column either way?
So is it "air distance"? Or is there any other distance table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Range Tables should be on the inside front cover of the *Ultimate Powers Book*

Martin's [*Ultimate Powers Book*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0880384131) (1986) on the power T16/Teleport Self says, "Column E on the Range Table shows the maximum distance a hero can teleport" (91). So one finds one's Teleport Self rank on Column E on the inside front cover Range Tables, an excerpt from which I've reproduced below:

| Rank | Range |
| --- | --- |
| Feeble | 2 miles |
| Poor | 25 miles |
| Typical | 250 miles |
| Good | 2,500 miles |
| Excellent | 25,000 miles |
| Remarkable | 250,000 miles |
| Incredible | 2.5 million miles |
| Amazing | 25 million miles |
| Monstrous | 250 million miles |
| Unearthly | 2.5 billion miles |
| [...] | 2.5 billion miles |

The Range Tables are, in fact, *really* important, and frustration will quickly ensue if tying to use an *Ultimate Powers Book* that doesn't include them.

Comment: Tnx............I looked EVERYWHERE but the front. that is an epic fail. tnx a lot!

Comment: @ThomasE.  You're welcome.  It's easy to miss.